# Core Graphics Context doesn't seem to return an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-graphics, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a `UICollectionViewCell` to try and print an number in the top right corner (gained from a Core Data store) to show the number of updates to a product.

With the way cells are reused, I'm finding that if I use code to draw into a `UIView` layer (using CALayer), when the cell is re-used, the `CALayer` remains and appears by the wrong product. Apparently, according to other posts on SO, adding subviews to cells is not a clever thing to do as they are reused etc.

So, I'm trying to create an image using Core Graphics (in a separate method) and have the image appear in the container `UIImageView`. Following a tutorial I can't seem to get an image to return.

I'm making the call as:

```
cell.messageCount.image = [self messageImageInRect:CGRectMake(48.0, 1.0, 21.0, 21.0)];
```

The method is:

```
-(UIImage *)messageImageInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    NSLog(@"I am inside");
    NSLog(@"I have rect as: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
    NSLog(@"I have the size as: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(rect.size));
    NSLog(@"I have the context as: %@", context);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    UIImage *testImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return testImage;

}
```

Which seems to be pretty basic.

NSLog statements are there to aid with trying to work out what's happening. But, according to the Logs, it seems to be working, however, I have no Image being returned (or displayed at least). And I have no idea why.

The Logs show:

```
2014-01-19 18:06:02.753 XXXXXXXX[62921:70b] I am inside
2014-01-19 18:06:02.754 XXXXXXXX[62921:70b] I have rect as: {{48, 1}, {21, 21}}
2014-01-19 18:06:02.754 XXXXXXXX[62921:70b] I have the size as: {21, 21}
2014-01-19 18:06:02.754 XXXXXXXX[62921:70b] I have the context as: <CGContext 0x10f133640>
2014-01-19 18:06:02.754 XXXXXXXX[62921:70b] I have test Image size as: {21, 21}
```

With the messageCount being defined in the UICollectionViewCell.

As is usual, this has been about 3 hours of my time, reading tutorial after tutorial and SO response after SO response and programming manual ...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing an ellipse which is completely outside of the context, so you don't see anything at all.

Change this:

```
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
```

to

```
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, CGMakeRect(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
```

Note that when you created the image context, you provided `rect.size`, but not `rect.origin`. Therefore, the context has no way of knowing that the things you draw at `rect.origin` are supposed to go into the top-left corner of the context. It's up to you to make that happen.

Here's another way to get the same effect. It's a bit easier because you only have to adjust for the rect's origin once; then you can do as much drawing you want using `rect` without adjusting again.

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
```

One more thing: you're going to find that you see the ellipse's fill, but not the stroke. That's because `CGContextFillPath` clears the context's current path after it draws. To both fill and stroke the path in one step:

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thanks. A newbie mistake sadly with the `CGContextDrawPath` - I'd deleted it from an earlier attempt. With the `rect.origin` stuff, I'm assuming this moves the co-ordinates of the `rect` I've supplied, to the `rect` I want to draw in?

Comment: Right, I think you get the idea.